# Render Jquery dialog

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have the following:

**application.js**

```
   //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require_tree .
    //
    //= require jquery-ui
    //= require jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min
    //= require datatable
    //= require highcharts
    //= require exporting
    //= require turbolinks


$('table').on('click', 'td', function(e) {

    $('.create_booking').dialog('open');
});
```

What I am trying to do is make my `<td>` elements open the Jquery-ui dialog and render the partial `booking_dialog` it is not doing that for reason I do not seem to understand. The above should work.

Comment: Please post the html code as it appears in the browser.

Comment: @ThiefMaster My page source for this particular page looks like the following: https://gist.github.com/4333277

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the dialog first:

```
$('.create_booking').dialog({
    autoOpen: false
});
```

After that you can use `$('.create_booking').dialog('open')` to show it. Also consider using an ID instead of a class for your dialog element. You only have one anyway, don't you?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/uJUuW/ (try clicking "open" first)

Comment: That was more of a comment. However, the "create the dialog first" part should fix your problem. In case it did fix it please rollback the edit - editing the question to add the fix from an answer makes the question obsolete...

Comment: I made the suggested changes to look like the following: https://gist.github.com/4336363 and it appears to not work

Comment: I do think the issue may lay within my partial which is why it is not working

Comment: Also you may have noticed I didn't have the `$(document).ready(function(){  });` Not that this made a difference, however I tested in the click function is firing and it is. Therefore there must be something wrong with my partial?